# How to make my apache web server public instead of local Wi-Fi?

Tags: php, html, apache, web

I am a complete beginner at web developing. I want to try accessing my web server through another device from another network. Likewise, I have managed to access it from the same Wi-Fi using my iPhone using my local IP, it ran similar to what I imagined but when I tried to connect to the server using another Wi-Fi it will not show anything. I think I have tried port forwarding, but I couldn't find an exact solution for that. Thank you in advance.
[Explanation of what any of the fillable slots means is very appreciated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFc2v.png)

Comment: Basically you are trying to make your local web server as a public server. 

I think that, the first thing that you should try to do is to unlock the 80 port in your router configuration. Then check if you have access to your web page by using your public IP(you can get that IP by using external websites like whatsmyip.org).
If you still don't have access, I suggest you to check your firewall rules, that probably are blocking those connections.

Comment: This is a router configuration question, rather than one on [tag:apache], [tag:php], [tag:web] or [tag:html] that you tagged, even though they all might be the reason for this question. I consider it off topic on stackoverflow (see [help/on-topic]), but as there are no relevant tags here, I'll leave them as they are.

Comment: https://dev.to/lloyds-digital/how-you-can-host-websites-from-home-4pke